# Problema al agregar características de SQL Analysis Services en Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition

Tags: sql-server, instalacion, sql-server-2017

Estoy tratando de agregar la característica de **SQL Server Analysis Services** (SSAS) en la instancia de mi **SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition** que corre sobre Windows 10 Home de 64 bits.

[image: Versión de la instancia de SQL Server]

Ya he revisado la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/install-windows/install-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017) y otros articulos donde explican como realizar la instalación, pero al momento de seleccionar las características a instalar, SQL Server Analysis Services no aparece en la lista:

[image: Ventana de selección de caracteristicas para SQL Server 2017]

Cabe aclarar que la instalación de la instancia fue realizada en la edición Express, pero se actualizó a la versión Enterprise para poder agregar ésta característica.

Cuando realizo los primeros pasos correspondientes para agregar SSAS, me pregunta por una carpeta de instalación y la especifico en la siguiente dirección:

C:\SQLServer2017Media\Express_ENU

[image: Selección de carpeta]

Espero puedan ayudarme en saber que está sucediendo o si hay otra manera de instalar esta característica.

**EDICIÓN:**

Este problema lo solucioné descargando una versión completa (en formato .iso) de SQL Server 2017 de la [página oficial de Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/sql-server/sql-server-downloads):

- Cabe destacar que se debe elegir correctamente el idioma de acuerdo con el Sistema Operativo. En mi caso el lenguaje del SO por default es inglés, y primero descargué el instalador en español, provocándome conflictos hasta que me bajé el instalador en inglés.

Una vez descomprimido el archivo de instalación `SQLServer2017-x64-ENU.iso` ejecuté el `setup.exe`, el asistente me reconoció la instancia ya instalada de SQL Server 2017 y me permitió agregar las características faltantes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si te fijas bien, estás apuntando a un medio que contiene la versión *Express* de SQL Server. Me parece que SSAS no viene habilitado en la versión *Express*, es por ello no lo tienes disponible al ejecutar el instalador. Saludos

Comment: Gracias! @MauricioContreras Probé descargando una versión completa (.iso) desde la página oficial de Microsoft, la descomprimí e inicié el setup.exe, automáticamente reconoció la instancia ya instalada del SQL Server y ahora al momento de agregar caracteristicas, aparecen completamente.

Comment: Me alegra que hayas logrado resolver tu problema. Saludos